# How do I lookup the closest row in a lookup data.frame based on multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe with data (v) and a lookup dataframe (l):

```
v <- data.frame(d = c(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-05'), as.Date('2019-01-30'), as.Date('2019-02-02')), kind=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), v1=c(1,2,3,4))
v
           d kind v1
1 2019-01-01    a  1
2 2019-01-05    b  2
3 2019-01-30    c  3
4 2019-02-02    a  4

l <- data.frame(d = c(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-04'), as.Date('2019-02-01')), kind=c('a','b','a'), l1=c(10,20,30))
l
           d kind l1
1 2019-01-01    a 10
2 2019-01-04    b 20
3 2019-02-01    a 30
```

I would like to find the closest row in the `l` dataframe corresponding to each row in v using the columns: `c("d", "kind")`. Column `kind` needs to match exactly and maybe use `findInterval(...)` on `d`?

I would like my result to be:

```
           d kind v1 l1
1 2019-01-01    a  1 10
2 2019-01-05    b  2 20
3 2019-01-30    c  3 NA
4 2019-02-02    a  4 30
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R implementation but it would be
>   interesting to see others

I tried `findInterval(...)` but I don't know how get it to work with multiple columns

Comment: Try with a rolling join `setDT(v)[l, l1 := i.l1, on = .(d, kind), roll = -Inf]`

Comment: `setDT(...)` must not be from a base-R. I don't have access to that function

Comment: it is from data.table `library(data.table)`  You want only `base R` soluiont?

Comment: I would prefer a base-R solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot in base-R only. (I do believe that `data.table` will do this much more elegantly, but I appreciate your aversion to bring in other packages.)

Split each frame into a list of frames, by `kind`:

```r
v_spl <- split(v, v$kind)
l_spl <- split(l, l$kind)
str(v_spl)
# List of 3
#  $ a:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ d   : Date[1:2], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-02"
#   ..$ kind: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1
#   ..$ v1  : num [1:2] 1 4
#  $ b:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ d   : Date[1:1], format: "2019-01-05"
#   ..$ kind: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 2
#   ..$ v1  : num 2
#  $ c:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ d   : Date[1:1], format: "2019-01-30"
#   ..$ kind: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 3
#   ..$ v1  : num 3
```

Now we determine the unique `kind` we have in common between the two, no need to try to join everything:

```r
### this has the 'kind' in common
(nms <- intersect(names(v_spl), names(l_spl)))
# [1] "a" "b"

### this has the 'kind' we have to bring back in later
(miss_nms <- setdiff(names(v_spl), nms))
# [1] "c"
```

For the in-common `kind`, do an interval join:

```r
joined <- Map(
  v_spl[nms], l_spl[nms],
  f = function(v0, l0) {
    ind <- findInterval(v0$d, l0$d)
    ind[ ind < 1 ] <- NA
    v0$l1 <- l0$l1[ind]
    v0
  })
```

Ultimately we will `rbind` things back together, but those in `miss_nms` will not have the new column(s). This is a generic way to capture exactly one row of the new columns with an appropriate `NA` value:

```r
emptycols <- joined[[1]][, setdiff(colnames(joined[[1]]), colnames(v)),drop=FALSE][1,,drop=FALSE][NA,,drop=FALSE]
emptycols
#    l1
# NA NA
```

And add that column(s) to the not-yet-found frames:

```r
unjoined <- lapply(v_spl[miss_nms], cbind, emptycols)
unjoined
# $c
#            d kind v1 l1
# 3 2019-01-30    c  3 NA
```

And finally bring everything back into a single frame:

```r
do.call(rbind, c(joined, unjoined))
#              d kind v1 l1
# a.1 2019-01-01    a  1 10
# a.4 2019-02-02    a  4 30
# b   2019-01-05    b  2 20
# c   2019-01-30    c  3 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact match you would go:

```
 vl <- merge(v, l, by = c("d","kind"))
```

For your purposes, you can transform d into additional variables for year, month or day and use the *merge*

Comment: This does not return the expected output.